# Definition of transitive group

Tags: group-theory, permutations, definition, symmetric-groups

I need a definition of a transitive group that's accessible to someone who's just started learning group theory (so won't know about actions and orbits etc.). I've written the following:

> A permutation group $S_X$ is transitive if there exists an element $\alpha \in S_X$ such that $x^{\alpha}=y$ for all $x, y \in X$.

Is there anything wrong with this? Furthermore, is the notation I've used what you'd usually see or could it be improved to be something more conventional? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might as well fix $x.$

Comment: Imo the way you wrote this is wrong. You should universally quantify $x, y$ before you existentially quantify $\alpha$. Obviously the $\exists \alpha \forall x,y$ interpretation is wrong, so most people won't read it that way, but this is literally what you wrote.

Comment: *Pace* @diracdeltafunk, if user356 wants to be accessible to learners, then they probably don't fall in the category of people who would resolve the ambiguity automatically. It is definitely ill-advised to put quantifiers at the beginning and end of a statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A group $G$ of permutations on a set $X$ is transitive if for every pair of elements $x, y$ of $X$, there is a $\sigma$ in $G$ such that $\sigma(x) = y$ (or $x^\sigma = y$, if you prefer that notation). (I've avoided using your notation $S_X$, which strongly suggests the group of all permutations of $X$, which always acts transitively.) So, for example, the subgroup of $S_4$ generated by the transpositions $(1\,2)$ and $(3\,4)$ is not transitive, because it contains no permutation mapping $1$ to $3$.